# In coffeescript how do I make a variable available in my controller and return the results via ajax to fill a datatable?

Tags: ajax, json, datatable, coffeescript

So I have a view with a datatable (javascript library to create pretty tables) that is generated like in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast)
Briefly, the datatable is created in the server side and a new class creates a json response that is rendered in the view

So in my generated view I have a link that I want to trigger an ajax event when clicked and has a data attribute,

```
 link_to( "#{sir.sir_id}" , '#', :data => {'sir-id' => sir.id}, remote: true )
```

I fetch the value of that data attribute in coffeescript this way:

```
  $("a[data-sir-id]").click ->
   data_sir_id = $(this).data("sir-id")
```

which works fine

I want to make that value (sir-id) available in my controller so I can get the associated model objects and show them in the same view via ajax, it would fill the content of another datatable (this one would not need server-side processing)

How do I create and feed this new datatable with ajax source?

I think I could return some other json object to the view if I manage to use sir_id in my controller but the view has already rendered json when first created.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data to the controller using a post method.

```
$("a[data-sir-id]").click ->
  data_sir_id = $(this).data("sir-id")
  $.ajax
    type: 'POST'
    url: '/some-path'
    data: {sir_id: data_sir_id}
    success: console.log('success posting sir-id')
    dataType: 'json'

#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "/some-path", to: "some_controller#some_view"
end

#app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_view
    SomeModel.find_by_sir_id(params[:sir_id])
  end
end
```

I would like to say that if you can form a link_to with "#{sir.sir_id}" in your view file it seems to me that the sir_id should already be available to you in your controller and you wouldn't need to use ajax. Nevertheless, I hope this ajax solution is what you were looking for :)